# why is averaging neighbours so incredible slow?

Tags: python, performance, scipy

The task is to average the image pixels on the values of the neighbours in a 3X3 window.

The image is a standard image of 2.5 MB.

In order to avoid the edge cases, i give them a value of -1 and filter them out.

When running the program it terminates after 624 seconds. Why is it so slow?

The program looks very minimalistic but i am sure i miss something.

```
import scipy
import numpy as np
import scipy.misc
import scipy.ndimage
import timeit




def average_neighbours(mat):

    interesting = mat[mat>=0]
    return np.average(interesting)


def run_program():
    vienna = scipy.misc.imread('kaertnerstrasse.jpg')

    vienna1 = scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter(vienna, function=average_neighbours, size=(3,3,1),mode="constant",cval=-1.0)

    scipy.misc.imsave('kaertnerstrasse3-3.jpg', vienna1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = timeit.default_timer()

    run_program()

    stop = timeit.default_timer()

    print stop - start
```

Here is the profiler data. It looks like the standard operations i want to do take much time. Is it possible to do it faster?

```
      479086307 function calls (479086303 primitive calls) in 739.517 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.004    0.004  739.517  739.517 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 BmpImagePlugin.py:173(DibImageFile)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 BmpImagePlugin.py:27(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 BmpImagePlugin.py:55(_accept)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 BmpImagePlugin.py:61(BmpImageFile)
        1    0.006    0.006    0.006    0.006 GifImagePlugin.py:28(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 GifImagePlugin.py:47(_accept)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 GifImagePlugin.py:54(GifImageFile)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.268    0.268 Image.py:1394(save)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.014    0.014 Image.py:1750(new)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.029    0.029 Image.py:1786(fromstring)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.011    0.011 Image.py:1943(open)
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:2082(register_open)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:2094(register_mime)
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:2104(register_save)
       10    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:2114(register_extension)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:219(_conv_type_shape)
        2    0.003    0.001    0.011    0.005 Image.py:290(preinit)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:371(_getdecoder)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:387(_getencoder)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:449(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:460(_new)
      6/2    0.003    0.000    0.224    0.112 Image.py:503(__getattr__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.221    0.221 Image.py:522(tostring)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.015    0.015 Image.py:577(fromstring)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:606(load)
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:83(isStringType)
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:92(isTupleType)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Image.py:98(isImageType)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.183    0.183 ImageFile.py:124(load)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.004    0.004 ImageFile.py:227(load_prepare)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ImageFile.py:236(load_end)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ImageFile.py:254(StubImageFile)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ImageFile.py:283(_ParserFile)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ImageFile.py:30(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ImageFile.py:330(Parser)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.266    0.266 ImageFile.py:466(_save)
        9    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ImageFile.py:516(_safe_read)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ImageFile.py:69(ImageFile)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ImageFile.py:72(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 JpegImagePlugin.py:121(SOF)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 JpegImagePlugin.py:168(DQT)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 JpegImagePlugin.py:261(_accept)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 JpegImagePlugin.py:267(JpegImageFile)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 JpegImagePlugin.py:272(_open)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 JpegImagePlugin.py:35(<module>)
       24    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 JpegImagePlugin.py:41(i16)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.266    0.266 JpegImagePlugin.py:420(_save)
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 JpegImagePlugin.py:50(Skip)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 JpegImagePlugin.py:54(APP)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 PngImagePlugin.py:151(PngInfo)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 PngImagePlugin.py:169(PngStream)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 PngImagePlugin.py:308(PngImageFile)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 PngImagePlugin.py:34(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 PngImagePlugin.py:453(_idat)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 PngImagePlugin.py:75(ChunkStream)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 PpmImagePlugin.py:18(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 PpmImagePlugin.py:46(PpmImageFile)
 29942784   64.011    0.000   81.737    0.000 _methods.py:43(_count_reduce_items)
 29942784  126.522    0.000  398.092    0.000 _methods.py:53(_mean)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _ni_support.py:38(_extend_mode_to_code)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _ni_support.py:55(_normalize_sequence)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _ni_support.py:70(_get_output)
 29942784  151.188    0.000  701.104    0.000 ex1.py:12(average_neighbours)
        1    0.007    0.007  739.513  739.513 ex1.py:18(run_program)
        1    0.000    0.000  738.947  738.947 filters.py:1115(generic_filter)
 29942784   67.220    0.000  549.916    0.000 function_base.py:436(average)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 genericpath.py:85(_splitext)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ntpath.py:161(splitext)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 numeric.py:141(ones)
 29942789   19.069    0.000   50.684    0.000 numeric.py:394(asarray)
 29942784   14.466    0.000   37.300    0.000 numeric.py:464(asanyarray)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 numeric.py:773(flatnonzero)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.247    0.247 pilutil.py:103(imread)
        1    0.002    0.002    0.313    0.313 pilutil.py:130(imsave)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.236    0.236 pilutil.py:174(fromimage)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.042    0.042 pilutil.py:206(toimage)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 pilutil.py:34(bytescale)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 re.py:188(compile)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 re.py:226(_compile)
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_compile.py:178(_compile_charset)
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_compile.py:207(_optimize_charset)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_compile.py:32(_compile)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_compile.py:359(_compile_info)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_compile.py:472(isstring)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_compile.py:478(_code)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_compile.py:493(compile)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:138(append)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:140(getwidth)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:178(__init__)
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:182(__next)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:195(match)
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:201(get)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:257(_escape)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:301(_parse_sub)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:379(_parse)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:67(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:675(parse)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:90(__init__)
       11    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 string.py:220(lower)
       24    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 string.py:229(upper)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.012    0.012 string.py:308(join)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 type_check.py:237(iscomplexobj)
        1    0.014    0.014    0.014    0.014 {PIL._imaging.fill}
        1    0.004    0.004    0.004    0.004 {PIL._imaging.new}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_sre.compile}
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {apply}
       41    0.193    0.005    0.193    0.005 {built-in method decode}
        1    0.266    0.266    0.266    0.266 {built-in method encode_to_file}
      548    0.025    0.000    0.025    0.000 {built-in method encode}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method pixel_access}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method setimage}
       26    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {chr}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {divmod}
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {getattr}
 29942787    9.386    0.000    9.386    0.000 {hasattr}
 89828369   34.448    0.000   34.448    0.000 {isinstance}
 29942786   12.578    0.000   12.578    0.000 {issubclass}
       40    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {max}
      591    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 {method 'close' of 'file' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'copy' of 'dict' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'fileno' of 'file' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'flush' of 'file' objects}
       11    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'get' of 'dict' objects}
       13    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'has_key' of 'dict' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'items' of 'dict' objects}
        1    0.012    0.012    0.012    0.012 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
       11    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'lower' of 'str' objects}
 29942784   19.872    0.000  417.964    0.000 {method 'mean' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'nonzero' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'ravel' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
       79    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'read' of 'file' objects}
 29942784  114.221    0.000  114.221    0.000 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'rfind' of 'str' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'seek' of 'file' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'sort' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.013    0.013    0.013    0.013 {method 'tostring' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
       24    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'upper' of 'str' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {min}
 59885574   54.461    0.000   54.685    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.array}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.copyto}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.empty}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.zeros}
        2    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {open}
       63    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {ord}
 29942785   13.675    0.000   13.675    0.000 {range}
        1   37.843   37.843  738.947  738.947 {scipy.ndimage._nd_image.generic_filter}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {zip}


739.529455192
```

The line function_base.py:436(average) is intersting. It looks like it takes most of the time.

Comment: You could try to use profile https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html to check what takes so long

Comment: Saying the image is 2.5MB doesn't give any indication of how many pixels wide and how many pixels tall it is - it may be 80,000x80,000 pixels of something that compresses very well. What are its pixel dimensions?

Comment: vienna.shape is (2736L, 3648L, 3L)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try to replace the generic_filter method with a more general and maybe better suited solution. What you are basically trying to do is a convolution with a kernel of size 3x3x1 and values 1/9:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import scipy.misc
import scipy.ndimage
import scipy.signal
import timeit

def run_program():
    my_image = scipy.misc.imread('my_image.png')

    kernel = np.ones((3, 3, 1))
    kernel /= kernel.size

    my_image_smoothed = scipy.signal.fftconvolve(my_image, kernel, mode='valid')
    scipy.misc.imsave('my_image_3x3.png', my_image_smoothed)

if(__name__ == '__main__'):
    start = timeit.default_timer()

    run_program()

    print timeit.default_timer() - start
```

**[UPDATE]**

To respect the original image size you could use the mode 'same' instead of 'valid' for fftconvolve. This will automatically zero pad your image. However to get better results at the boundaries of the image pad the image with one of the modes promoted by numpy's pad function

```
numpy.pad(array, pad_width, mode=<'constant'|'edge'|'reflect'|'symmetric'|...>)
```

and use the fftconvolve mode 'valid' on the alternately padded image.

```
padding = [(shape // 2, shape // 2) for shape in kernel.shape]
my_padded_image = np.pad(my_image, shape, mode='edge')
my_image_smoothed = scipy.signal.fftconvolve(my_padded_image, kernel, mode='valid')
```

**[/UPDATE]**

I am not sure if it will run a lot faster but it should at least compensate the method call overhead.
On a test image with 4876x2278 pixels the code needs ~40 seconds (Hard drive is an SSD)

Best regards

Comment: The edges are lost with this method. unless there are other modes that keep them.

Comment: @M4artini Updated my answer based on your legitimate critisism

Comment: So this is an inherent slowness in python?

Comment: @DavidMichaelGang : Method call overhead is inherent to almost every programming language. So if there is a simple AND readable solution to avoid repetitive calling of functions, I would use it.

Comment: I am using now opencv which is really fast import cv2
import timeit

start = timeit.default_timer()

vienna = cv2.imread('kaertnerstrasse.jpg')
vienna1 = cv2.blur(vienna,(20,20))
cv2.imwrite('kaertnerstrasse-opencv.jpg', vienna1)
stop = timeit.default_timer()

print stop - start   takes less than one second